# Unicode characters in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a problem with showing the characters in unicode encoding. For example, in XML I have a text which I transfer to html with help of XSLT.

The text is for example 
`"Najlepší"` and characters "`š`" and "`í`" in this form, are displayed as they should be. But I tried to convert them to unicode (supposedly) with this website http://itpro.cz/juniconv/ so the text now looks like `Najlep\u0161\u00ED` with "`š`" and "`í`" characters in form of `\u0161` and `\u00ED`.

I expected the converted characters to display normally, I tried UTF-8, UTF-16, ISO-8859-1, no luck so far.

My XML and XSLT are fairly simple. In XML shown here I tried various character encodings and combinations

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>

<element1>
<name>ľ š č ť ž ý á í é &#9730; u"\U+010C" \u00C1 u"\U0001D504" \u0161 \u010D \u0165 \u0165 \u017E \u00FD \u00E1 \u00ED \u00E9</name>

</element1>


</test>
```

and XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <xsl:for-each select="test/element1">
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </body>
</html>
```

and output looks like this

[image]

What am I doing wrong? for example Eclipses plugin resource bundle editor is able to show these characters properly.

EDIT: I did not realize this will cause confusion - what I need is, when the HTML is produced by transformation, and is opened in web browser, it should display `\u00C1` as `Á`

Comment: To me they seem to be shown exactly as they should. Why do you want to convert them into some other form?

Comment: Q: How exactly are you "displaying" when it looks "messed up"?  It sounds like you're doing everything correctly in XML .. and everything correctly with XSLT ... and the translated text even displays correctly in Eclipse.  Where exactly *doesn't* it "display" correctly?  Q: Is UTF-8 the correct encoding for your XML?

Comment: @paulsm4 Oh I forgot - when I open the HTML that is produced by transformation, in any web browser, it looks like exactly what I written, but I'd like to convert "\u00C1" parts of the text to normal characters like "ľ š č" and others

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen They need to be in that form because we are using some other software which is unable to decode characters in the form they are displayed, we found out, the software can do that with those Unicode characters, but we also need to display them properly, which I am unable to do

Comment: OK: so the problem was you were "converting" characters using this site: http://itpro.cz/juniconv/.  It converts Unicode to Java entities (e.g. `"\u010C"`), but what you *REALLY* want is to convert to XML entities (e.g. `&#010C`).

Comment: @paulsm4 Yup, exactly. I thought that in XML it will work the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice how `&#9730;` is treated correctly... ;)

In fact, your various notations such as `\U+010C`, `\u00C1`, etc are programming language-specific notations, that "happen to be" converted into corresponding Unicode codepoints.

As the W3C specifies in [Unicode in XML and other Markup Languages](https://www.w3.org/TR/unicode-xml/) 1.1,

> Characters are denoted using the notation used in the Unicode
>   Standard, that is, an optional U+ followed by their hexadecimal
>   number, using at least 4 digits, such as "U+1234" or "U+10FFFD". **In**
>   **XML or HTML** this could be expressed as `"&#x1234;"` or `"&#x10FFFD;"`.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that, although I am not sure right now if the other software that we use to process the output will be able to work with characters encoded as "&#x1234;" instead of the "\U something something" form. But I will definitely try that, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Java and Javascript have a convention for representing Unicode characters as `\Uhhhh`.

XML has a similar but different convention, it uses `&#xhhhh;`.

You are using the Java/Javascript notation in XML, and that isn't going to work.

(Note there's also a subtle difference between the two notations when it comes to characters above xFFFF: the Java/Javascript convention splits the character into a surrogate pair and represents each half separately, whereas XML represents the Unicode codepoint as a single character reference. Hence the XML notation is variable length with semicolon as a terminator, while the Java/Javascript notation is always 4 hex digits.)